# Drupal Devel module query log

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, zend-optimizer

I have a newly completed Drupal site and somewhere along the line I picked up a bug where the time to first byte is taking 10-12sec. At first glance it appears that the issue is with the DB queries.

So, I loaded the Devel Module to start debugging the queries but I cant activate the query log  options since the the host of this domain has the ridiculously old v3.2.1 Zend Optimizer running on the server and wont upgrade or disable it for me.

So my question is, What alternative do I have to Devel Module to debug the DB queries? Anything would be appreciated... Module or a manual way of reviewing such queries for issues.

Its Drupal 7.3 on an IIS server with basically no control over the server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best thing you can do is to copy whole drupal installation and get it running on your local machine, then you will be able to use devel module, but also other mysql debugging tools.

maybe you will find out that drupal is running smooth on local machine, then you will need to change your server configuration or change provider. big drupal sites needs really big server customizations, testing and optimalisations

Comment: Thanks Tomas! I decided to move the site to my own Apache servers instead and realised from the first page load on the new server that the site is running as it should. My client is moving hosting to a more reliable host